# C# TCP server wait for 2 clients to respond

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, client, server

I'm currently working on a server/client project.
My question is, how the server can wait for two specific connections to respond?

Server:

```
private TcpListener tcpListener;
private Thread listenThread;
private List<Connection> ConList = new List<Connection>();
Queue queue = new Queue();

public struct Connection
{
     public Stream stream;
     public StreamWriter streamw;
     public StreamReader streamr;
     public TcpClient tcpC;
}


private void ListenForClients()
{
     this.tcpListener.Start();

     while (true)
     {
         try
         {
            Connection c = new Connection();
            c.tcpC = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            c.stream = c.tcpC.GetStream();
            c.streamr = new StreamReader(c.stream);
            c.streamw = new StreamWriter(c.stream);

            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));

            clientThread.Start(c);

            queue.Enqueue(c);
         }
         catch()
         {
             break;
         }
     }
 }
 private void HandleClientComm(Object client)
 {
     Connection con;
     con = (Connection)client;

     ConList.Add(con);

     byte[] message = new byte[4096];
     int bytesRead;

     while (true)
     {
         bytesRead = 0;

         try
         {

                bytesRead = con.stream.Read(message, 0, 4096);

                string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message, 0, message.Length);
         }
         catch
         {
             //Socket error
             break;
         }

         if (bytesRead == 0)
         {
             //Client lost connection

             con.stream.Close();
             con.tcpC.Close();
             ConList.Remove(con);
             con = null;

             break;
         }
     }
 }

 private void QueueTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (queue.count >= 2)
      { 
            Connection c1;
            Connection c2;

            c1 = new Connection();
            c1 = (Connection)queue.Dequeue();

            c2 = new Connection();
            c2 = (Connection)queue.Dequeue();

            //Start thread which waits for a response from both connections
      }
 }
```

Each connection gets placed in queue and if queue.count >= 2 (timer checks every 20 seconds) a new thread should be startet which waits for a responds from both of the clients with a 10 seconds timeout. I tried to figure something out for 3 days but cannot find a good way to do it. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple TPL based listener/responder without needing to dedicate a thread to the process.

```
    private TcpListener _listener;

    public void OnStart(CommandLineParser commandLine)
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, commandLine.Port);
        _listener.Start();
        Task.Run((Func<Task>) Listen);
    }

    private async Task Listen()
    {
        IMessageHandler handler = MessageHandler.Instance;

        while (true)
        {
            var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Without the await here, the thread will run free
            var task = ProcessMessage(client);
        }
    }

    public void OnStop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    public async Task ProcessMessage(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                var message = await SimpleMessage.DecodeAsync(stream);
                _handler.MessageReceived(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _handler.MessageError(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            (client as IDisposable).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off a point about your QueueTimer_Tick() function.  In it you have the following code:

```
c1 = new Connection();
c1 = (Connection)queue.Dequeue();
```

The first line of this isn't needed, it creates a new Connection object that is immediately overwritten by whatever you pull off the queue.  Alos what not use a typed queue in the same way as you use a typed List?

To answer your question what I think you are after is the [Socket.Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) method.  It will take a list of sockets and check them for readability and it also allows a timeout to be specified.

To acheive what you want you'll need to call Select() in a loop where each time you check for readability of the clients who haven't yet become readable.  You'll also need to work out how much of your 10 second delay each call to select has used and adjust the timeout accordingly.

So in psuedo code:

```
create L1 a list of sockets that are to be readable
set the timeout T to 10 seconds
while L1 is not empty
   copy L1 to a tempory list L2
   Socket.Select(L2,T)
   If a timeout then exit loop
   Remove the socket(s) that are readable from L1
   recalculate T based on how long the Select took
End While
```

NB: The TcpClient.Client() method gets the Socket for a TcpClient.